# Why do my funnels in Google analytics show 0 but the goal shows a high number?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics

I am new to Google Analytics but can not find a solution to this issue on the Google Forums. I am setting up a basic Goal. My website has pages for case studies, what my company does, how we deliver. The goal for is users to end up at the contacts page to email the company. We want to see how users would go through

1) what we do NOT REQUIRED
2) how we work
3) case studies
Goal - contact

When I verify the Goal, I am given a 19.97 conversion rate. However when I go to the funnel visualisation page, it shows 0% at each funnel but it has a number at the end Goal.

I know that user are visiting these parts of the website. I am not sure what is causing this.

1) The first step is not required
2) I am using the specific webpage url for the step e.g. /what/

I have some questions:

What could be causing this? I have just made this goal however I intend to make more and display the reports on different dashboards and would like to set them up correctly.

Does it take time for the results to render if a new goal is saved? I have read 24 hours in forums but can not confirm this.

The landing page of my company's website has is just e.g. company.com. Am I supposed to use the specific URL in a Funnel step, how should the landing page be stated in the Funnels?

Thanks

Comment: why the java, javascript and php tags?

Comment: I was under the impression that I needed a minimum of 5. I have taken out the Java and PHP tags but it may well be caused by a  coding issue and the Analytics code is written in JS.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this by adjusting the start date to when the Goal was first created, where as it was previously set to the date the website went live and testing was being performed.

Can data only start being collected for funnels when the goal is created?

Comment: Correct, goals are not retroactive.